# Imaginary roots in $\widetilde{E}_8$

Tags: lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

Consider the root system of a Kac-Moody algebra. Denote by $\alpha_i$ the simple root associated with node $i$
by for $i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ and by $\beta$ the simple root associated with $n$.

The Dynkin diagram for $\widetilde{E}_8$ is 
\begin{align}
\circ - \circ - & \circ - \circ - \circ - \circ - \circ - \circ \\
& \ | \\
& \ \bullet
\end{align}
where $\bullet$ corresponds to the simple root $\beta$. The degree of a root is the coefficient of the root at $\beta$.

Are there some reference of imaginary roots of type $\widetilde{E}_8$? I only find one imaginary root $\gamma=3  \beta + 2  \alpha_1 + 4  \alpha_2 + 6  \alpha_3 + 5  \alpha_4 + 4  \alpha_5 + 3  \alpha_6 + 2  \alpha_7 + \alpha_8$. The root $\gamma$ has degree $3$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In an (untwisted?) affine root system, aren't all imaginary roots $\mathbb{Z}$-multiples of some fundamental imaginary root $\delta$ (which I think is what you denote by $\gamma$)?

Comment: Yes, that's right (twisted or not).  If you have found one imaginary root $\delta$ that is primitive, then the imaginary roots are exactly the integer multiples of $\delta$.  A good reference is Chapters 4 and 5 of Kac' book "Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras" or MacDonald's "Affine root systems and Dedekind's $\eta $-function".

Comment: Specifically, you want Theorem 5.6 on page 64 of the Kac book (which refers to tables on pages 54 and 55).